# Find the search keyword in nesting array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, flatmap

```js
 let arr = [
      {
        id:{key:1, name:"apple"},
        fruits:[{id:{key:1.1,name:"green apple"}},{id:{key:1.2, name: "red apple"}}]
      },
      {
        id:{key:2, name:"grapes"},
        fruits:[{id:{key:2.1,name:"green grapes"}},{id:{key:2.2, name: "black grapes"}}]
      },
      {
        id:{key:3, name:"berries"},
        fruits:[{id:{key:3.1,name:"strawberries"}},{id:{key:3.2, name: "blueberries"}}]
      },
      {
        id:{key:4, name:"banana"},
        fruits:[{id:{key:4.1,name:"yellow banana"}}]
      }
    ]

const search = "pp"

    function filterResult(obj) {
      const re = new RegExp(search, "ig")
      return re.test(obj.id.name)
    }

    //this gives result of outer id array only 
   const searchResult = [
...Object.values(arr).filter((v) => {  
     let tempArr = [];
      if (filterResult(v)) {
        tempArr.push(v);
         return [...tempArr,...(v.fruits).filter((vv) => {
            return filterResult(vv);
          })]    
      }
    })
].map((res)=>res.id);

console.log(searchResult);
```

But now how to search in nested array (fruits) of arr
I tried to use flatMap, but I feel i did something wrong.

```
const searchResult = [
...Object.values(arr).filter((v) => {  
     let tempArr = [];
      if (filterResult(v)) {
        tempArr.push(v);
         return [...tempArr,...(v.fruits).filter((vv) => {
             filterResult(vv);
          })]    
      }
    })
]
```

I want "search Result" result like : because they pp keyword in all ( parent + child on same level)

```
[{id:1, name: "apple"}, {id:1.1,name:"green apple"},{id:1.2, name: "red apple"}]
```

PS: not allowed to use `flatMap`

Comment: Please correct the syntax issues. JavaScript statements cannot start with `...`.

Comment: @trincot Done that , please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```js
/**
 * Sample data provided.
 */
const arr = [
  {
    id: { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
    fruits: [{ id: 1.1, name: 'green apple' }, { id: 1.2, name: 'red apple' }]
  },
  {
    id: { id: 2, name: 'grapes' },
    fruits: [{ id: 2.1, name: 'green grapes' }, { id: 2.2, name: 'black grapes' }]
  },
  {
    id: { id: 3, name: 'berries' },
    fruits: [{ id: 3.1, name: 'strawberries' }, { id: 3.2, name: 'blueberries' }]
  },
  {
    id: { id: 4, name: 'banana' },
    fruits: [{ id: 4.1, name: 'yellow banana' }]
  }
];

/**
 * Find all fruits whose name contains the query.
 *
 * @param {*} array items to iterate through
 * @param {*} query search query
 * @returns {Array} array of objects whose property name contains the query
 */
const search = (array, query) => {
  /**
   * MDN documentation on Array.prototype.reduce
   * ------------------------------------------------------
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
   * ------------------------------------------------------
   */
  return array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return [
      ...acc,
      /**
       * Add the item to the accumulator if the item name contains the query.
       */
      ...item.id.name.includes(query) ? [item.id] : [],
      /**
       * Add all fruits whose name contains the query to the accumulator.
       */
      ...item.fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.name.includes(query))]
  }, []);
};

console.log(search(arr, 'pp'));
```

**Output**

```js
[
  { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
  { id: 1.1, name: 'green apple' },
  { id: 1.2, name: 'red apple' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A call of `filter` on the input array can only return top level objects, never inner objects. Moreover, it is not necessary to call `Object.values` on an array. Just iterate the array.

I would use a recursive generator for this purpose. This way you can have input that is even deeper nested with objects:

```js
function* filterRec(arr, re) {
    for (const {fruits, ...obj} of arr) {
        if (re.test(obj.name)) yield obj;
        if (re.test(obj.id?.name)) yield obj.id;
        if (fruits) yield* filterRec(fruits, re);
    }
}

const filter = (arr, search) => [...filterRec(arr, RegExp(search, "i"))];

// Demo
const arr = [{id:{id:1, name:"apple"},fruits:[{id:1.1,name:"green apple"},{id:1.2, name: "red apple"}]},{id:{id:2, name:"grapes"},fruits:[{id:2.1,name:"green grapes"},{id:2.2, name: "black grapes"}]},{id:{id:3, name:"berries"},fruits:[{id:3.1,name:"strawberries"},{id:3.2, name: "blueberries"}]},{id:{id:4, name:"banana"},fruits:[{id:4.1,name:"yellow banana"}]}];
const search = "pp"
const searchResult = filter(arr, search);
console.log(searchResult);
```